# Prove or disprove that T:[0,2π] -> [0,2π] given by Tx = sin(2014x) is a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, banach-spaces

i know that if we assume $T:[a,b] \to [a,b] $
and if $|T'(x)| ≤ α \space \forall \space a≤x≤b$
then T is a contraction .

but unsure of how to apply that to this question

Comment: Find $T'(x)$ to begin with. How large can its modulus be?

Comment: You may run into trouble if  $ T'x \geq 1 $

Answer (score 1):

I think that [you should add $\alpha < 1$ in your statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419392/show-that-derivative-less-than-1-implies-contraction). So, you just have to show that there exists at least one $x\in[0, 2\pi]$ such that this inqequality doesn't hold. Do you have any ideas? Just take the derivative of the $\sin(2014x)$.

Comment: @Anon: Well, you're almost right. Supremum is a tricky thing: the function might never reach it (not in your case, though). So, I suggest just taking the biggest value at $x = 0$: $|2014\cos(2014\cdot 0)| = |2014*\cos(0)| = |2014\cdot 1| = 2014 > 1$. One point is enough to show that it is not a contraction.

Answer (score 0):

I just did |T'(X)|  = |2014 cos(2014x)|
                    < sup (2014 cos(2014x))
                    and it was not smaller than 1
so T is not a contraction
is that right?

Comment: Note: I don't think that you are supposed to answer your question. I mean, you can, but not with another question :)
You can use the comments instead.