# Show that $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$, $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is a contraction mapping

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Show that $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$, $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is a contraction mapping.

I want to show that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le c|x-y|$ where $0\lt c\lt 1$.

I tried to write $f(x)=e^{-x}$ into Taylor polynomials but It's not helpful.
Can anyone give me any idea of how to prove this?

Answer (score 5):

I thought about suggesting using the mean value theorem. But
$$\left|\frac{f(0)-f(x)}{0-x}\right|=\frac{1-e^{-x}}x\to1$$
as $x\to0$ so there is no $c<1$ with $|f(x)-f(y)|\le c|x-y|$
for all $x$, $y\in[0,\infty)$.

If you consider $f$ on $[a,\infty)$ for $a>0$ it does become a contraction.

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to Lord Shark the Unknown's answer. In general, if your function $f(x)$ is nice enough, you can show that it is a contraction mapping if there's a $c<1$ with $|f'(x)|<c$ for all $x$.

See [Show that derivative less than 1 implies contraction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419392/show-that-derivative-less-than-1-implies-contraction)